# Use .splice() on JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

We remove child of a certain `html` element through `JQuery` via:

```
$(PARENT_SELECTOR).children(CHILD_SELECTOR).remove()
```

But how can I make this behave like `.splice()` method (e.g. removing on the `DOM` tree the given index and offset). For instance:

1. Remove the last three children. Here I'll most probably use:

   ```
   for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      $(PARENT_SELECTOR).children().last().remove()
   }
   ```
2. Remove 4th to 6th children. Here I'll use:

   ```
   $(PARENT_SELECTOR).children().eq(3).remove()
   $(PARENT_SELECTOR).children().eq(4).remove()
   $(PARENT_SELECTOR).children().eq(5).remove()
   ```
3. Remove 5 elements starting from the 5th child ( this is the real scenario where I want to have a `.splice()`-like function for `JQuery` ):

   ```
   var starting = 5,
       index = 5

   // I haven't tested this yet.
   for(var x = index + starting; x > index; x--) {
       $(PARENT_SELECTOR).children().eq(x - 1).remove()
   }
   ```

And the list goes on... I can make my own case-to-case scripts for each scenarios *[, that's easy]*. I'm just wondering if `JQuery` has already it's own feature like this-- it will make my scripting shorter and will not make me to repeat writing similar codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [$.slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) is really what you are looking for. Below is the example:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>

$( "li" ).slice( 2, 4 ).remove();
```

Just keep in mind that `.slice()` starts with index 0, so example above will remove the third to fifth child.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_slice.asp) method selects a subset of elements based on its index.
This method is used to limit the selection of elements in a group, by a start and end point: the start parameter is a starting index (starts at 0) from which to create the subset, and the stop parameter is an optional ending point.
You can find the better explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_slice.asp) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").slice(1).css("background-color", "red");
    $("p").slice(2,4).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>para 0.</p>
<p>para 1.</p>
<p>para 2.</p>
<p>para 3.</p>
<p>para 4.</p>
```